# "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './iterator.js'

Tags: vega, vega-embed

I am suddenly getting the follow errors and I have no clue how to fix them:

```
Object
loc: "1224:2-26"
message: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './iterator.js' in 'C:\\Users\\MyApp\\node_modules\\vega-embed\\build'"
moduleIdentifier: "C:\\Users\\MyApp\\node_modules\\@angular-devkit\\build-angular\\src\\babel\\webpack-loader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2].use[0]!C:\\Users\\my-project\\node_modules\\@ngtools\\webpack\\src\\ivy\\index.js!C:\\Users\\MyApp\\node_modules\\source-map-loader\\dist\\cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!C:\\Users\\MyApp\\node_modules\\vega-embed\\build\\vega-embed.module.js"
moduleName: "./node_modules/vega-embed/build/vega-embed.module.js"
[[Prototype]]: Object

./node_modules/vega-embed/build/vega-embed.module.js:1224:2-26 - Warning: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './iterator.js' in 'C:\Users\MyApp\node_modules\vega-embed\build'
```

I also get the following warning when I build my app:

```
Warning: C:\Users\MyApp\src\app\components\vega\vega.component.ts depends on 'vega-embed'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
```

Can someone please help me understand what is wrong and how I can resolve fix these?

Comment: Saw this error today too. It's tracked in this issue https://github.com/vega/vega-embed/issues/780. For me it is not more than a warning though.